# Tabbed Page and mvvm Filter

Tags: xamarin

I have tab page with 4 tabs with each having their own ViewModel. On the tabPage i have a filter that should work for all of them. I am not quite sure how to approach this. Can you please help? DO I add filter to each of the ViewModels or do i have my own filter ViewModel? Or do i have to put all these 4 pages in one VM? I think that filter and own view model is the solution but then do i need another view where i will be filtering this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you create 5 VM's.
four VM's for 4 pages and 1 Base VM.

Add your logic of Filters in Base VM and then all four pages VM's will inherit from Base VM.